# Active directory - unlock password

Tags: active-directory, password

we use an active directory in win server 2008.
Also, we use Office 365. I'll be brief.
One of our users works from his home in Finland. All the time he exceeds the number of times to enter his password correctly. So he messages me because he thinks there is a problem with the VPN.
I just go into the active directory and **unlock** the username.
Is it possible to save the password, so he will not need to write?
Or increase the number of times of a wrong password.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the number of failed attempt in the GPO (see [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh994563(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)).

Go to **Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Account Policies\Account Lockout Policy**, then change the **Account Lockout Threshold**.